# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly - WEB FORMS

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm project in Web Form, and I am passing an array to a method that will make a post to a URL specifies. However, after I run the project and send the array to the method, it breaks with the error stated in the title.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://MINHAURL.COM/QUE-RECEBE-O-POST/");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=https://MINHAURL.COM/QUE-RECEBE-O-POST/";

        streamWriter.Write(data);
    }

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var user = new Usuarios();
    var lista = new string[]
    {
        user.name,
        user.dt_nascimento,
        user.cidade
    };

    webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(lista, null);
}
```

Comment: well handle the exception. You need to deal with all kinds of errors when you download stuff, from connection problems to disk full errors.

Comment: I did not understand